# How to add logo to Contributions - Receipt (on-line)

Tags: message-templates, receipts

I am using Civi 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.1

I need to make our online receipts look nicer.  I tried adding a table to the template Contributions - Receipt (on-line) and adding the HTML for the logo image, but nothing changed in the test.  How do I add the logo to the receipts and do other styling?

Thank you.

Added Screenshot

[image]

Comment: The source code for the message template "Contributions - Receipt (on line)", which is a System Workflow Message, already contains at least 2 tables.  At about Line 16, the first table contains the following text <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
  <!-- You can add table row(s) here with logo or other header elements -->
  <!-- END HEADER -->
I assume that it is at this point, you are trying to insert some more code.  Is that correct and if so, could you elaborate on the code that you have tried to insert?

Comment: That is correct. The code looks like this <tr><td><img src="https://oursite.org/images/logo.jpg"></td></tr>

Comment: The page uses XHTML (not HTML) and therefore all XHTML elements have to be closed.  Could you try putting in a closing forward slash in the image element so that it reads <img src="oursite.org/images/logo.jpg" /> and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you.  That didn't work either. I tried several times and cleaned the cache.  The result was the same each time.  Below is my code. It might help if I can see what someone else is using.

Comment: `code`<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<tr>
<td><img src="https://oursite.org/wp-content/uploads/Header-001-1.jpg" />

</td>
</tr>



  <tr>
   <td>

    {if $receipt_text}`code`

Comment: that ";" that is showing up in the above text is NOT in my code. It is just showing that in this forum for some reason.

Comment: hmmm.....can you confirm that you have an absolute path to your image e.g. <img src="http://oursite.org/wp-content......." />  Also that there is a whitespace before the ending /> in the img element?
One other thing, I notice there are <center></center> tags in the message template that are not supported in HTML5 and I don't know whether the same applies to XHTML.

Comment: For some reason, "http://" has been stripped out of the absolute path mentioned in my comment above

Comment: I added a screenshot above. Is that how it is in yours?

Comment: Just to rule this out, can you confirm that the image loads when you just enter it in a web browser?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that.

Comment: I've just used one of my own images in the code shown in your screen shot, using the closed image element, saved the message template as an html file and run it in Firefox.  The image showed up correctly.  So it would seem that there may be something wrong with your image file.  Maybe XHTML doesn't like characters like hyphens (or white spaces if there are any) in the file name.  Could you try it again using another image with perhaps a less complicated file name?

Comment: Thank you. You are helping me confirm that i m at least doing it correctly, but something is interferring.  I will experiment with it and let you know what happens.

Comment: I tried renaming the image without hypens. I tried different images, I tried adding a complete table with the <table> tags.  I tried using different email addresses to receive it.  Nothing is working. I am hoping to see a copy of someone else's code, so I can compare it to mine.

Comment: The code in the message template that I have is nearly 500 lines long but I cant find an easy way of sending it or letting you see it.  There seems to be no facility on here of attaching a file to a comment.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I appreciate that.  If you mean the entire code is almost 500 lines, maybe just copy and paste the part where your code starts and ends with a small piece of civi's orginal code at the beginning and end, so I can find my place.

Comment: Try putting your img tag into the Off-Line receipt header and see if that works. I had to do that in the past. But in one of the updates that reversal problem went away.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did try that also.  The same code is in both of them.

Comment: I tried to post the code in your question above but big parts of it got stripped out for reasons I don't understand.  Instead, Ive posted it in Pastebin which you can view at this link https://pastebin.com/qaKn2F5N

The code is just copied from my civi message templates but I've inserted some example <img> code that I've used.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. My code is exactly the same as yours. It still didn't work.  So I copied it into a page  to see what happens.  The page shows the image I want in the email header.  So this means for some reason the EMAIL isn't picking it up and sending it.  Any idea why?

Comment: Might be time to disable all plugins but Civi and see if the problem goes away. If that does not work, try one of the vanilla twenty-ish themes and see if it works then.

Comment: Twenty Ten is the theme we are using and the only installed plugin is Loginizer, which I just disabled.  The results were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.  I am almost too embarrassed to tell you what the problem was.

All this time, I was working on the Contributions Receipts, but doing my tests on a Membership page.  As soon as I noticed there was also a Membership receipt it all came clear. So, if anyone else ever runs into this issue, remember if it's a contribution but not a membership, it uses the Contribution Receipt.  If it's a membership it uses the membership receipt.

Thank you everyone for trying to help me figure this one out.  You did open my eyes to a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Good to get these things clarified for others.